# Cannot load fixtures when testing Django

Tags: django, testing, django-fixtures

I hope not to make a fool of myself by re-asking this question, but I just can't figure out why my fixtures are not loaded when running test. I am using python 2.7.5 and Django 1.5.3.

I can load my fixtures with `python manage.py testserver test_winning_answers`, with a location of `survey/fixtures/test_winning_answers.json`.

```
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
Installed 13 object(s) from 1 fixture(s)
Validating models...

0 errors found
```

My test class is doing the correct import:

```
from django.test import TestCase
class QuestionWinningAnswersTest(TestCase):

    fixtures = ['test_winning_answers.json']
    ...
```

But when trying to run the test command, it cannot find them:

```
python manage.py test survey.QuestionWinningAnswersTest -v3
...
Checking '/django/mysite/survey/fixtures' for fixtures...
...
No json fixture 'initial_data' in '/django/mysite/survey/fixtures'.
...
Installed 0 object(s) from 0 fixture(s)
...
```

I suspect I am missing something obvious, but cannot quite figure it out... any suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Did you maybe try to debug `TestCase._fixture_setup` to see what fixtures are loaded?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is trying and failing to find a file called 'initial_data' in '/django/mysite/survey/fixtures' rather than failing to load 'test_winning_answers.json'

Try adding a file called 'initial_data.json' containing just '[]'

Comment: This works indeed `Installing json fixture 'initial_data' from '/django/mysite/survey/fixtures'. CommandError: No fixture data found for 'initial_data'. (File format may be invalid.)`.

Comment: Of course I still don't know why it won't accept the fixture file I would like to use.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why, but `python manage.py test survey -v3` displays `Installed 0 object(s) from 0 fixture(s)`.

Following mariodev's recommendations, I looked into `django/test/testcases.py`, and changed the `call_command('loaddata'...)` to use `verbosity=3`. This clearly showed me that the fixture was properly loaded:

```
Installing json fixture 'test_winning_answers' from '/django/mysite/survey/fixtures'.
Installed 13 object(s) from 1 fixture(s)
```

The error that prompted me to look into fixtures loading was actually a typo I had made...

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the app was missing from INSTALLED_APPS configuration for Django to find the fixture file.